# sum columns without duplicates in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have these 3 tables: tables, reservation and table_reservation. The last one is the pivot, the thing is that I want to sum the amount of each reservation according to the given date, but without duplicates, that is, there is a reservation with 3 tables taken, these 3 records are added in the pivot table and sum 3 times the amount of a reservation, what I do not want.

I leave the tables and my code.

`table_reservation`

```
| date       | table_id | reservation_id |
| 2019-06-12 | 2        | 1              |
| 2019-06-12 | 3        | 1              |
| 2019-06-12 | 4        | 1              |
| 2019-06-12 | 1        | 2              |
```

`reservation`

```
| id | name        | emp_id | amount | other    |
| 1  | Luis Miguel | 2      | 200    | vdvvdvdv |
| 2  | carloz      | 2      | 234    | dwdq     |
```

`tables`

```
| id | name |
| 1  | A1   |
| 2  | B2   |
| 3  | A2   |
| 4  | A4   |
| 6  | B4   |
```

PHP code

```
    DB::table('reservation')
    ->join('table_reservation', 'reservation.id', '=', 'table_reservation.reservation_id')
    ->join('tables', 'table_reservation.mesa_id', '=', 'tables.id')
    ->join('empleados', 'reservation.emp_id', '=', 'emp.id')
    ->select('reservation.id',DB::raw('group_concat(tables.name) as y'),'reservation.name', 'emp.name as x','reservation.amount','reservation.other', 'table_reservation.date', DB::raw("SUM(reservation.amount) as count"))
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(reservation.amount) as count"))
    ->distinct()
    ->groupBy('reservation.id')
    ->where('table_reservation.date',$date)->get();
```

I get the following:

```
[{"count":"600"},{"count":"234"}]
```

It should be 200 instead of 600

Comment: ideally you should also provide the generated SQL

Comment: Most likely because off the one-to-many relations and the way you join and wrote your code/SQL you have to use `->select('reservation.id',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT tables.name) as y'),'reservation.name', 'emp.name as x','reservation.amount','reservation.other', 'table_reservation.date', DB::raw("SUM(DISTINCT reservation.amount) as count"))
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(reservation.amount) as count"))`  .. notice i added `DISTINCT` in `SUM()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` to counteract the aggregated multiplying caused by the JOIN's

Comment: It works for me. Thanks!

Comment: No problem when in doubt when aggregating and needing JOINs always use delivered tables... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... SUM(...) ... FROM table ...) alias ... INNER JOIN ... ` then you never can go wrong with aggregated multiplying..

Comment: Do you think you can help me to add all the records? Do not add them, it returns this: [{"id":"1","y":"B2,A2,A4","nombres":"Luis Miguel","x":"RR.PP de prueba","importe":"200","observaciones":"vdvvdvdv","fecha":"2019-06-12","count":"200"},{"id":"2","y":"A1","nombres":"Luis Miguel","x":"RR.PP de prueba","importe":"234","observaciones":"dwdq","fecha":"2019-06-12","count":"234"}]